# Allow access to wamp server on WAN

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm developing a site in local, and I would like to allow access to it to my friend through the web.

So I opened ports in my router and Firewall, but now I'm stuck configuring Apache.
Looked for it and it seems it's around those lines but I can't get it to work, when trying to connect, I get the forbidden message, so it seems port configuration is ok and it's really on server configuration...

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride none
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

And further

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

First of all, am I right?
And if so, I just don't what to allow or write...

note : WAMP version 3.0

fullversion is : 3.0.6 for a 64 bits platform.

I'vre tried combination if ruleset, bu t I can't get my hand on it

Comment: your friend in on the same network?

Comment: Have you port forwarded port 80 on your router? Just opening the ports is not enough!

Comment: What is the full version number of your WAMPServer

Comment: no, he's not in the same network, as I said I want him to access it through wan/internet.
not sure I've forwarded it, but my error is 403, so I assume it is, since it's a server answer, no?
WAMP is 3.0.6 64 bits.
Than ks guys

Answer (score -1):

Just open your website link in your browser and get your IP-Address from your network you are currently connected. Give the IP to your friend and the port number. He will become able to access it.

For example, your wifi/ethernet IP is **192.168.10.8** and port is **3000**, so your friend give such **192.168.10.8:3000** in his browser and he will access it. Thanks